# How to check whether an image source exists

Tags: php, image

I have limited space in my server. So, I am looking for an alternative for hooking up image URLs to my site like a product image.

What I would like to do is input an URL then load an image without refreshing the whole page.

Here is my idea:

input "any url" then submit

```
if url is image and existing {
    display the image
}
else if (url is a non-image) or (url is image but not existing) {
    display a default image
}
```

I tried `getimagesize` but it was so heavy. `curl` is not functioning on my server, so I am trying to do is use jQuery or JavaScript or something.

Comment: Which server technologie do you have? PHP, ASP, JSP, Ruby, Python?

Comment: I use PHP, javascript, jquery, ajax, json.

Comment: thanks for the revision of the title rekire. Anyways, does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: There are several options. readfile, get_file_contens, curl, even non php technics like htaccess with mod_proxy. It is hard to say because I don't know your server configuration. It is possible that all that methodes are disabled for secutity reasons.

Comment: maybe i'll stick for awhile with getimagesize even if it is taking too long.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I'm using something like this:

HTML

```
<img src="http://www.yoursite.com/img/someimage.jpg" onerror="NoImage(this);">
```

Javascript part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    function NoImage(p){
        p.src="http://www.yoursite.com/img/nopic.gif";
    }
</script>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

use fopen to check if that image exists u dont have to read the full content

http://www.astro.keele.ac.uk/oldusers/rno/Computing/File_magic.html

( u should restrict that possible urls cause auf bandwidth stealing from other pages - and maybe some copyright problems caused by that images )

Comment: is fopen more faster than getimagesize?